# Animate div height + 20px

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

right now I have :

```
$("#emm").delay(3600).animate({
        top: '0px',
        marginTop: '120px'
    }, 500);
```

But how do I get it like this :

```
$("#emm").delay(3600).animate({
        top: '0px',
        marginTop: '(#emm height + 20px')
    }, 500);
```

Basically I want the marginTop to animate the div (#emm) height + 20px.
Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do :

```
$("#emm").delay(3600).animate({
    top: '0px',
    marginTop: $('#stroke').height() + 20 + 'px'
}, 500);
```

Please see this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/78u1sn0c/)

Comment: Hey my bad it's not #emm height but I need the #stroke height so I cannot use $(this).. my bad..